# How to remove the MacOS Legacy System Extension signed by Golden Frog Inc (kextstat does not help)

Tags: kernel-extensions

After every update of my MacOS, an error message like this is shown to me upon restart:

[image: Legacy System Extension]

I deleted VyprVpn long time ago, but this system extensions seems to still run on my laptop.

In System Information -> Software -> Extensions, there is nothing that says VyprVpn or Golden Frog. I guess that's because "Golden Frog" is who signed the extension, but the extension name is different.

Running `kextstat | grep -v com.apple` does not show anything with "Golden Frog" either, so [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310757/how-can-i-identify-3rd-party-kernel-extensions-in-macos/310758#310758) does not help.

How can I identify and remove that extension completely?

Please note that my question is not solely about how to remove an extension, but also how to find / identify it based on the error message where it only says who signed that extension.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310757/how-can-i-identify-3rd-party-kernel-extensions-in-macos/310758#310758

Comment: See https://support.vyprvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039607451-How-do-I-uninstall-the-VyprVPN-macOS-app-

Comment: indeed the best method is using official uninstaller

Comment: I don't trust that company and don't want to run yet another piece of software from them. Hence asking about how to identify what the system extension is and how to delete it - without installing anything extra from that company. I don't need more software from them. I rather need to remove the footprints of some of their old software I once had.

Answer (score 2):

About this mac -> System report -> Software section in the sidebar

Relevant sections are "Legacy Software", "Extensions", and "Disabled Software". You can also get the list of all application using `system_profiler` and grep for the said code sign identity.